# VBA Code to Delete Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I would like a VBA code to delete the content in a cell that’s in Column A when the content in a cell in Column E is cleared same row

This is what I have, here is what I want what I've altered the code and it stops working

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim n As Integer
    For n = 5 To 75 
        Application.EnableEvents = False 
        If VarType(Cells(n, 1)) = vbEmpty Then 
            Cells(n, 4).ClearContents 
            Cells(n, 5).ClearContents 
            Cells(n, 6).ClearContents 
            Application.EnableEvents = True 
        End If 
    Next n 
End Sub
```

I need this specific code for when content is cleared in Column E (Cells(n,5)) to clear content in column A (Cells(n,1)) without having to go over and delete it

Comment: Your code is disabling Events and only re-enabling them if cell A75 is empty.  Which means that code will never run again (because it is an Event) once A75 is not empty.  Move `Application.EnableEvents = True` outside your `If`.  (And you will need to manually re-enable events to get things working again.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a loop in a `Worksheet.Change` event.  You are passing the Target (the cell being modified to the procedure).  This will do what you are looking for:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
     If Target.Column = 5 Then
           If Target.Value = vbEmpty Then
              Cells(Target.Row,1).ClearContents
           End If
     End If
End Sub
```